# How can I make a view with TabGestureReganizer in a UITableViewCell able to respond?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my custom `UITableViewCell` there's an `ImageView` which is able to be clicked and do an action.
But when I try to implements it, I find lots of problems.

1.When I click the Cell, the cell is clicked and highlighting, but my `imageView's` action is never shown.(I guess that the cell responded my touch before my `imageView` did)

2.When I add a button to the cell, the cell will respond the button event first and I wonder why?

3.I was told to use method `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to implement it, but if i has not only one this `imageView` in my cell, how can I implement?

Comment: Do you want the cell to do anything or will the image views only trigger an event?

Comment: Why are you making this so hard on yourself? Use a custom UIButton and you can run your action when button is pressed.

Comment: @danielM my cell will not do anything, just my imageViews will act an event

Comment: @SamBudda you are right! but i've already finished my custom imageView, so I don't want to waste time in rewriting one inheriting from uibutton. Or base on this issue, i would like to know if there's a way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

`isUserInteractionEnabled` defaults to `NO` for `UIImageView`. And for good reason --- you'd typically use a button with a background image for this. But what you're doing should work if you set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `YES`.